# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'indent'

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, module, indentation

I used indentation method in the code but it throws a error. Need solution please. My python version is Python 2.7.15+

Code:

```
import textwrap
s = 'hello\n\n \nworld'
s1 = textwrap.indent(text=s, prefix=' ')
print (s1)
print ("\n")
s2 = textwrap.indent(text=s, prefix='+ ', predicate=lambda line: True)
print (s2)
```

Code is taken from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/textwrap-text-wrapping-filling-python/)

Output Error:

```
python Textwrap5.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "Textwrap5.py", line 4, in <module>

    s1 = textwrap.indent(text=s, prefix=' ')

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'indent'
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using python 3?

Comment: Looks like you are on py2

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your file is located in a directory called textwrap or you have other file called textwrap in the same or parent directory.
Try changing the directory name or the file and see if it works

Comment: can you elaborate more. Thanks!

Comment: Hi
There may be another file named textwrap.py in your present directory. When you are importing the module textwrap, instead of importing the builtin python module, it is importing the module which you have created.

Answer (score 0):

Python2.7, textwrap doesn't have indent function available.

Either use `initial_indent` or `subsequent_indent` as per your requirement OR upgrade to Python3.x